# shell_exec() to call a php file returns incorrect output character encoding

Tags: php, shell, encoding, shell-exec

Ok, here's my scenario.

I have `file.php` that contains the following:

```
<?php
$output = shell_exec("php output.php");
echo $output;   
?>
```

And the `output.php` contains the following:

```
<?php
echo "This is my output!";
?>
```

When I run `file.php` from a web browser, I get the following output:

```
‹ ÉÈ,V¢ÜJ…üÒ’‚ÒEÿÿp³*š
```

However, when I run the same `php output.php` directly from the shell, I get the correct output:

```
This is my output!
```

Now I'm well aware that this is some sort of encoding issue, but I cannot for the life of me figure out how to resolved it.  I've tried setting the language using `putenv('LANG=en_US.UTF-8');`.  I also tried using `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');` and even trying to determine what encoding type is being outputted using `mb_detect_encoding($out, 'UTF-8', true);`. without result.

`exec()` produces the same, malformed output.

I would really appreciate if anyone can shed some light on this and can possibly provide some insight on what is happening between the shell_exec and the output of the file to cause the output to be malformed.

Comment: what happens when you do a `shell_exec("php -i")` ? Any clues?

Comment: I ran it, and it just produces a massive block of garble.  It seems like the output produced by `shell_exec()` is not correct when I run PHP through it.  If I run `shell_exec("whoami");` it returns the correct result, which is the current user.

Comment: have you tried putting the full path to your PHP executable (`shell_exec("/usr/bin/php output.php")`)?

Comment: yup, I actually thought of trying `shell_exec("/usr/bin/php output.php")` and it produced the same results.  Adding `#!/usr/bin/php` to the top of `output.php` doesn't change anything either :/

Comment: I also ran `file -bi output.php` in the shell, and it returned `text/plain; charset=us-ascii`.  I'm not sure if that means anything...

Comment: strange... how about `shell_exec("LANG=\"en_US.UTF8\" php output.php")`?

Comment: Yup, I tried that as well.  The output is the same `‹ ÉÈ,V¢ÜJ…üÒ’‚ÒEÿÿp³*š`

Comment: Hmm... have you considered calling an exorcist?

Comment: Rather than encoding, it looks like double compression problem. Check your webserver and php settings for `deflate`, `gzhandler` etc.

Comment: That was actually my first assumption.  Response header has `Content-Encoding: gzip`.  Could this be the culprit?

Comment: if output from `shell_exec` is also gzipped then yes

Comment: Finally!  Setting `ini_set('zlib.output_compression', 'Off');` fixes the problem.  Thanks to everyone for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the PHP output was being compressed twice, due to output compression being enabled.

The solution is to disable `zlib.output_compression` either by an entry in your `.htaccess` file, or by including the following at the top of your .php file:

```
ini_set('zlib.output_compression', 'Off');
```